# Option list generate in body, can it code in <script> in <head> section

Tags: javascript

https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/age-calculator.php

I am using the above script for age calculator but the problem is Date, Month & Year option list generate in the body, while I am trying to code it in the head section, struggling since 2 days but no luck.

```
<select name="day" size="1" class="form-control">
                  <script type="text/javascript">for(var j=1;j<32;j++)document.write("<option value="+j+">"+j+"</option>");
                  </script>
                </select>
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/mj0Lat4v/1/)**

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me. Why you are using `document.write()`?
And please share your full script thus we can easily understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks Sifat, here I am sharing fiddle link. https://jsfiddle.net/adampavlov/mj0Lat4v/

Answer (score 0):

Please add `defer` attribute in your script tag, this will run the script only once DOM has been rendered

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer>for(var j=1;j<32;j++)document.write("<option value="+j+">"+j+"</option>");</script>
```

Another approach can be to wrap for loop like this

```
document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
 if (document.readyState === "complete"){
   for(var j=1;j<32;j++)document.write("<option value="+j+">"+j+"</option>");
 }
});
```

If this does't works we can do this -:

```
<script>
  function ready() {
    for(var j=1;j<32;j++)document.write("<option value="+j+">"+j+"</option>");
  }

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Abhisar for the reply, code executed but outside the form.

Comment: outside the form, as in ??

Comment: The option list does not generate in <Select> tag, it executes just after <body>

Comment: we should wrap the for loop in document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
 if (document.readyState === "complete"){
  for(var j=1;j<32;j++)document.write("<option value="+j+">"+j+"</option>");
 }
});

Comment: Abhisar, Thanks for your effort but it still no luck.

Comment: Can you try changing the event to "DOMContentLoaded"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194697/discussion-between-abhisar-tripathi-and-adam-pavlov).